# Как расположить текст ссылки по центру ее фона?

Tags: css3, html5

[image: Это ссылки отображающиеся в ul-ном списке, рамки сделаны именно для ссылок]

Это ссылки отображающиеся в ul-ном списке, рамки сделаны именно для ссылок.
Как сделать так что бы текст не прилипал к левой стороне и был по центру?

Answer (score 0):

нужно просто написать:padding-left: (кол-во пикселей)px;

Answer (score 0):

`text-align:` определяет горизонтальное выравнивание текста в пределах элемента. В вашем случае выравнивание текста нужно сделать по центру `text-align: center`. Пример:

```css
body {
  background: #5ecfcc
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center; /*это то что вам нужно*/
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
</ul>
```